# Files written into SD card disappear after dismount

Tags: windows-10, sd-card, writing

I have copied a music folder into a SanDisk 16 Gb card from a Win10 computer.  The folder has been well copied, and I can play the files inside the folder.

I dismount the SD card (Windows "eject" menu command), remove it from the computer, reinsert it, and the folder is gone.

I've tried it a few times, and the result is always the same.  What is odd is that the files are indeed written into the SD card -- until the next mount.

Could it be a corrupted SD card?  It's the one I use in the head unit of my car (that's where I noticed the problem for the first time), and it has been exposed to heat and cold for about 8 years.  But then, why this odd behaviour?

Comment: use sync command first before eject

Comment: Yes, it can be corrupt, failing or even a fake.